# Alternative for EXTERNAL TABLES in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I'm having a question in external table concept in PostgreSQL. I'm using Enterprise version (EDB).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE DIRECTORY bdump AS '/u01/app/oracle/admin/SID/bdump/';

DROP TABLE alert_log;

CREATE TABLE alert_log (
  line  VARCHAR2(4000)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL
(
  TYPE ORACLE_LOADER
  DEFAULT DIRECTORY bdump
  ACCESS PARAMETERS
  (
    RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
    BADFILE bdump:'read_alert_%a_%p.bad'
    LOGFILE bdump:'read_alert_%a_%p.log'
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '~'
    MISSING FIELD VALUES ARE NULL
    (
      line  CHAR(4000)
    )
  )
  LOCATION ('alert_SID.log')
)
 /
```

I'm converting the above code in PostgreSQL. I created an extension file_fdw(Foreign Tables) and used the OPTIONS field to some extent. And I also want to know whether if we can specify BADFILE & DISCARDFILE in Postgres. Alternative for all_external_tables in PostgreSQL? Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: BADFILE & DISCARD file relate to sqlloader not external tables. For these look into the COPY command. FDW(foreign data wrapper) is for tables in other databases, Oracle external table is for files. Again i recommend looking at COPY. EDB offer something called EDB*Loader but i have never used this.

Comment: Actually file_fdw is for tables made from text files.

Comment: OP have you read up on the fdw for files here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/file-fdw.html ? Pretty sure the BADFILE and DISCARDFILE options are not directly available.